# UNION to one Line with Only 'Yes' Values

Tags: sql

I have a table that in an ideal world should only return 1 row per 'policy' for items that were sold as part of an up-sell.

I wish to roll this up into one line per 'PolRef@' and basically the 'Yes' should supercede 'No' should it exist in the column.

```
B@  PolRef@ Uk  Eu  Date    Ep500   Ep700   Ep3000  Keycare Wind    Ep350   Ep250   Legal   Totaladdon  Finance_yn
2   ROGX17PC01  Yes No  2017-07-31 00:00:00.000 No  No  No  No  No  NULL    NULL    NULL    62.00   Yes
2   ROGX17PC01  No  No  2017-07-31 00:00:00.000 No  No  No  No  No  NULL    NULL    Yes 32.00   Yes
```

This is an example, I know I could do a GROUP BY to GROUP the PolRef@ and then SUM the TotalAddon, how however can I have it so that if 'Yes' exists in A column for that 'PolRef@' that is shows it.

Essentially above's result should look like

```
B@  PolRef@ Agent   Uk  Eu  Date    Ep500   Ep700   Ep3000  Keycare Wind    Ep350   Ep250   Legal   Totaladdon  Finance_yn
2   ROGX17PC01  NULL    Yes No  2017-07-31 00:00:00.000 No  No  No  No  No  NULL    NULL    Yes 94.00   Yes
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

This is a prioritization query.  One method uses `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by PolRef@
                                order by uk desc -- 'Yes' comes before 'No'
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, you order by just 'UK' but there are other columns that may have 'Yes' in them, How could I cater for these. I appreciate your response.